# Contar URLs acabadas en ".pdf" en archivo csv

Tags: python, regex

Tengo un archivo .csv como el siguiente:

```
start_date,end_date,pollster,sponsor,sample_size,population,party,subject,tracking,text,approve,disapprove,url
2020-02-02,2020-02-04,YouGov,Economist,1500,a,all,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s handling of the coronavirus outbreak?,42,29,https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/73jqd6u5mv/econTabReport.pdf
2020-02-02,2020-02-04,YouGov,Economist,376,a,R,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s handling of the coronavirus outbreak?,75,6,https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/73jqd6u5mv/econTabReport.pdf
2020-02-02,2020-02-04,YouGov,Economist,523,a,D,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s handling of the coronavirus outbreak?,21,51,https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/73jqd6u5mv/econTabReport.pdf
2020-02-02,2020-02-04,YouGov,Economist,599,a,I,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of Donald Trump’s handling of the coronavirus outbreak?,39,25,https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/73jqd6u5mv/econTabReport.pdf
2020-02-07,2020-02-09,Morning Consult,"",2200,a,all,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of the job each of the following is doing in handling the spread of coronavirus in the United States? President Donald Trump,57,22,https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200214_crosstabs_CORONAVIRUS_Adults_v4_JB.pdf
2020-02-07,2020-02-09,Morning Consult,"",684,a,R,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of the job each of the following is doing in handling the spread of coronavirus in the United States? President Donald Trump,88,4,https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200214_crosstabs_CORONAVIRUS_Adults_v4_JB.pdf
2020-02-07,2020-02-09,Morning Consult,"",817,a,D,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of the job each of the following is doing in handling the spread of coronavirus in the United States? President Donald Trump,37,37,https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200214_crosstabs_CORONAVIRUS_Adults_v4_JB.pdf
2020-02-07,2020-02-09,Morning Consult,"",700,a,I,Trump,FALSE,Do you approve or disapprove of the job each of the following is doing in handling the spread of coronavirus in the United States? President Donald Trump,50,22,https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200214_crosstabs_CORONAVIRUS_Adults_v4_JB.pdf
2020-02-07,2020-02-09,Morning Consult,Politico,1996,rv,all,Trump,FALSE,"And, do you approve or disapprove of how each of the following have handled the response to the coronavirus? President Trump",39,35,https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200213_crosstabs_POLITICO_RVs_v1_AUTO.pdf
2020-02-07,2020-02-09,Morning Consult,Politico,700,rv,R,Trump,FALSE,"And, do you approve or disapprove of how each of the following have handled the response to the coronavirus? President Trump",71,8,https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200213_crosstabs_POLITICO_RVs_v1_AUTO.pdf
2020-02-07,2020-02-09,Morning Consult,Politico,788,rv,D,Trump,FALSE,"And, do you approve or disapprove of how each of the following have handled the response to the coronavirus? President Trump",15,60,https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200213_crosstabs_POLITICO_RVs_v1_AUTO.pdf
2020-02-07,2020-02-09,Morning Consult,Politico,508,rv,I,Trump,FALSE,"And, do you approve or disapprove of how each of the following have handled the response to the coronavirus? President Trump",34,33,https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200213_crosstabs_POLITICO_RVs_v1_AUTO.pdf
```

Quiero contar el numero de veces que se repite la palabra "Huffington Post" y el numero de veces que hay URLs que sigan el patrón siguiente: Empiecen por http o https y acaben en .pdf

He realizado lo siguiente:

```
import csv
import re

path = "mipath"
with open(path, "r") as file1:
    file1 = file1.read()
    # Contamos el numero de occurrencias de Huffington Post
    counter1 = file1.count('Huffington Post')
    # Contamos el numero de occurrencias de urls terminadas en .pdf
    occ = re.findall(r"(https?:\/\/.*\.pdf+$)", file1)
    print('The pattern Huffington_Post appears', counter1, "times")
    print(len(occ))
```

Sin embargo, obtengo lo siguiente:

```
The pattern Huffington_Post appears 112 times
1
```

No entiendo porque es 1 si le estoy diciendo que me encuentre todos los casos. Quizás deberia iterar por filas? No acabo de ver como. Gracias.

Comment: lo quieres hacer leyendo el `.csv` o tambien puede ser con `pandas`?

Comment: Con pandas también me vale pero entonces creo que deberia cambiar el conteo de Huffington Post

Comment: pues si, dare una solucion de ambas formas :)

Comment: @jachguate la estaba leyendo :(

Comment: @Christian. era una buena respuesta para otro problema. No aplicaba para este.

Comment: @jachguate bueno igual gracias, me había olvidado de esta pregunta, ahora si voy a elaborar la respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El símbolo `$` coincide con el final del string, a menos que se use el modificador [`re.MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE), en cuyo caso ahí sí coincide con el *final de una línea*.

```
occ = re.findall( r"https?:\/\/.*\.pdf$", file1, re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: Cuestión de preferencia personal, pero yo hubiese usado `\.pdf$` nomás... Me imagino que no es tan necesario buscar que tenga `"http://"` antes.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno vamos con la primera forma, para eso nos apoyamos de `Pandas` así transformamos los datos a un DataFrame, y luego usamos su funcion `.apply()` para aplicarle un *filtro* y para hacer ese *filtro* vamos a usar una expresion `lambda` y una expresion regular

```py
#importamos
import pandas as pd
import re

#leemos el archivo
df = pd.read_csv(path)

#generamos una expresion regular
regex = re.compile(r'.pdf$')

#convertimos los datos a un DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

#aplicamos un filtro y contamos los elementos
urls = df['url'].apply(lambda x: regex.findall(x)).value_counts()
print(urls[0])#12
```

La expresión regular dice que coincida con cada string que finalice con `.pdf`. En cuanto al filtro, lo que hace la función lambda es  aplicar la expresión regular en cada elemento del campo `url` y con `value_count()` contamos los elementos, esto nos retorna la cantidad de elementos en este caso `['.pdf']` si coincide o `[]` si no coincide. usamos `value_count()` ya que si no hay coincidencias el `df` contendrá múltiples índices y para contar en múltiples índices lo hacemos con `value_count()`

No encontré una forma efectiva de hacerlo en la forma como tu lo haces :(, por lo que no hay segunda forma, si tienes alguna duda me avisas.

Answer (score 1):

Vale hay que hacer unas aclaraciones sobre tu código y de esta forma darte una solución "*Vanilla Python*" que no afecte tu entusiasmada búsqueda de *"Huffington Post"*:

```
file1 = file1.read()
```

file1.read() guarda un unico string en file1, donde los saltos de linea se guardan como los \n de toda la vida.

```
occ = re.findall(r"(https?:\/\/.*\.pdf+$)", file1)
```

El ancla ***$*** buscara ocurrencia al FINAL de *file1* (sin contar los saltos de linea), es decir, *re.findall* buscara en *file1* la primera ocurrencia de "http" y luego ira directamente al final de TODO el *file1* donde de "casualidad" termina en ".pdf", y se come todo texto que abarca entre el primer "http" y el ultimo ".pdf" dando un valor de 1 (cantidad de elementos en la lista generada), entonces sin mucha modificación podrías simplemente quitar el ***$*** y funcionará:

```
occ = re.findall(r"(https?:\/\/.*\.pdf+)", file1)
```

-----------------------Resultado de prueba----------------------

```
https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/73jqd6u5mv/econTabReport.pdf
https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/73jqd6u5mv/econTabReport.pdf
https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/73jqd6u5mv/econTabReport.pdf
https://d25d2506sfb94s.cloudfront.net/cumulus_uploads/document/73jqd6u5mv/econTabReport.pdf
https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200214_crosstabs_CORONAVIRUS_Adults_v4_JB.pdf
https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200214_crosstabs_CORONAVIRUS_Adults_v4_JB.pdf
https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200214_crosstabs_CORONAVIRUS_Adults_v4_JB.pdf
https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200214_crosstabs_CORONAVIRUS_Adults_v4_JB.pdf
https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200213_crosstabs_POLITICO_RVs_v1_AUTO.pdf
https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200213_crosstabs_POLITICO_RVs_v1_AUTO.pdf
https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200213_crosstabs_POLITICO_RVs_v1_AUTO.pdf
https://morningconsult.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/200213_crosstabs_POLITICO_RVs_v1_AUTO.pdf
> Cantidad de urls encontrados:  12
```

O bien puedes mantener el ancla ***$*** pero agregarle la bandera *re.MULTILINE* donde la [documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) dice que al ser usada provocara lo siguiente en cuanto al ***$***:

> "El caracter de patrón '$' buscara al final de un string y al final de
> cada linea (inmediatamente precedida de cada salto de linea)".

Quedando el codigo de la siguiente forma:

```
occ = re.findall(r"(https?:\/\/.*\.pdf+$)", file1, flags = re.MULTILINE)
```

Sugerencia: aunque esto no afectara la respuesta, deberías quitar el símbolo "+" después de "pdf" porque si llega a suceder un error de texto en la url (lo dudo mucho) podria aceptar "pdffff" xD

*Espero que te sirva mi respuesta~*